# Multiple table of contents (on first page and last page)

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex

I need to put tables of contents on the beginning of the document and also at the last page. When I am using `\tableofcontents` second time it appears empty.

I want to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

%first toc
\tableofcontents

\section{Test}
test test

\section{Test 2}
test test

\newpage

%second toc - generates empty
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve the same toc on the last page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example use the `shorttoc` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{shorttoc}
\begin{document}

%first toc
\shorttoc{Contents}{2}

\section{Test}
test test

\section{Test 2}
test test

\newpage

%second toc
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

With the `memoir` class's `article` option.

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

%first toc
\tableofcontents

%\section{Test}
\chapter{Test} Use \chapter instead of \section
test test

%\section{Test 2}
\chapter{Test 2}
test test

\newpage

%second toc
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```